# limit in question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I click in ask question and get the following error:
[image]

How can I ask new question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you'll have to wait six months (since your last question). You've been warned before that your questions were (on average, including deleted questions) poorly received, and if question quality doesn't improve, you'll eventually get question banned. Posting good answers might help in relieving the ban; editing poor questions might help too. For details, see the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232)